# cannot display item by passing value from another component

Tags: reactjs, destructuring

I wanna display my cart item inside my CartList component but for some reason, it doesn't work out...Is there anything wrong with the way i destructure the cart variable able or anything? please help me! Thank you so much!

context.js:

```
class ProductProvider extends React.Component {
  state = {
    products: storeProducts,
    detailProduct: detailProduct,
    cart: storeProducts,
    modalOpen: false,
    modalProduct: detailProduct
  };

  getItem = (id) => {
    const product = this.state.products.find((item) => item.id === id);
    return product;
  };

  addToCart = (id) => {
    let tempProducts = [...this.state.products];
    const index = tempProducts.indexOf(this.getItem(id));
    const product = tempProducts[index];
    product.inCart = true;
    product.count = 1;
    const price = product.price;
    product.total = price;

    this.setState(() => {
      return (
        { products: tempProducts, cart: [...this.state.cart, product] },
        () => console.log(this.state)
      );
    });
  };

  openModal = (id) => {
    const product = this.getItem(id);
    this.setState(() => {
      return { modalProduct: product, openModal: true };
    });
  };

  closeModal = (id) => {
    this.setState(() => {
      return { modalOpen: false };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ProductContext.Provider
        value={{
          ...this.state,
          addToCart: this.addToCart,
          openModal: this.openModal,
          closeModal: this.closeModal
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </ProductContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Cart.js:

```
import React from "react";
import CartColumns from "./CartColumns";
import CartList from "./CartList";


const ProductContext = React.createContext();
export default class Cart extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        your cart
        <ProductContext.Consumer>
          {(value) => {
            if (value && value.length > 0) {
              return (
                <div>
                  <CartColumns />
                  <CartList value={value}/>
                </div>
              );
            } 
          }}
        </ProductContext.Consumer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

CartItem.js:

```
import React from "react";

function CartItem() {
  return <div>this is a cart item</div>;
}

export default CartItem;
```

CartList.js:

```
import React from "react";
import CartItem from "./CartItem"

export default class CartList extends React.Component {
  {value =>{
    return <div>
    {cart.map((item) => {
      return (
        <CartItem key={item.id} value={value} item={item}/>
      )
    }}
  </div>;
  }}
  
}

export default CartList;
```

Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/cart-code-addict-buz0u?file=/src/cart/CartList.js

Comment: what are you trying to do in `CartList`. Your syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

first of all fixed your cartList component

```
import React from "react";
import CartItem from "./CartItem"

export default function CartList (props) {
   const {cart} = props
    return (
      <div>
        {cart.map((item) => (
            <CartItem key={item.id} item={item} />
        ))}
      </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: but my cart item is still not being rendered tho...

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: so i 've set my cart intitial state to storeProducts (check in App.js) and when i try to dispay the cart item in the cartlist using cart.map, there will be 8 lines of texts being rendered in corresponse with my 8 products, that's what i mean